# How can I query a mongodb document with Dictionary<Enum, int>?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Using mongodb-csharp driver (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver)

I have the following classes & enums:

```
public enum PropertyType {
  Unknown,
  Age,
  Weight,
  Gender
}
public class Data {
  public Dictionary<PropertyType, Int32> Props {get;set;}
}
```

I can read and save data that looks like this.

```
{
  Props: {
    1: 28,
    2: 220,
    3: 0
  }
}
```

What I cannot do is query for "Data" with Props[PropertyType.Age] == 28.. see below code:

```
var data  = from d in collection where d.Props[PropertyType.Age] == 28 select d;
```

The error I get is:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'data.Props.get_Item(PropertyType.Age) is not supported.'

Help me obiwan kenobi your my only hope.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```cs
var data  = from d in collection where d.Props.Any(x => x.Key.Equals(PropertyType.Age) && x.Value == 28) select d;
```

Comment: `System.NotSupportedException: 'The expression tree is not supported: {document}{Props}'`

Comment: I need the answer to this as well

Comment: I wonder if anyone had found the answer to this question?